# How to separate (split) 10.00K

Tags: r

I have a variable in the data set with values

```
10.00K
0.45K
12.00M
```

etc.
How to separate (split) this variable into two variables like:

```
10.00   K
0.45    K
10.00   M
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> library(readr)
> library(stringr)
> library(dplyr)
> vec <- c('10.00K', '0.45K', '12.00M')                      
> df <- data.frame(vec = vec)
> df
     vec
1 10.00K
2  0.45K
3 12.00M
> df %>% mutate(value = parse_number(vec), units = str_extract_all(vec, '[A-Z]+'))
     vec value units
1 10.00K 10.00     K
2  0.45K  0.45     K
3 12.00M 12.00     M
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::extract` and use regex to extract the parts that we need.

```
tidyr::extract(df, col, c('col1', 'col2'), '(.*)(.)')

#   col1 col2
#1 10.00    K
#2  0.45    K
#3 12.00    M
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("10.00K", "0.45K", "12.00M")), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr` with `sep` specified as regex lookaround to split between a digit (`(?<=[0-9])`) and an upper case letter (`(?=[A-Z])`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   separate(col, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep="(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])", 
           convert = TRUE)
#   col1 col2
#1 10.00    K
#2  0.45    K
#3 12.00    M
```

---

Or using `base R` with `read.csv` after creating a delimiter with `sub`

```
read.csv(text = sub("([A-Z])$", ",\\1", df$col), header = FALSE)
#     V1 V2
#1 10.00  K
#2  0.45  K
#3 12.00  M
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("10.00K", "0.45K", "12.00M")), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `regmatches`

```
as.data.frame(
  do.call(
    rbind,
    regmatches(df$col, gregexpr("[^[:alpha:]]+|[[:alpha:]]", df$col))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
     V1 V2
1 10.00  K
2  0.45  K
3 12.00  M
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(col = c("10.00K", "0.45K", "12.00M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```